# Vanishing Functions: Extension

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Given a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$.
Consider a closed subset $F\subseteq X$.
(Then it is locally compact and Hausdorff too.)

> Does every continous function $f:F\to\mathbb{R}$ that vanishes at infinity
>   extend to a continuous function $\tilde{f}:X\to\mathbb{R}$ (that vanishes at infinity too)?

For an open subset $U\subseteq X$ this would work
simply by extending it trivially as it vanishes at infinity.

Also the usual spaces provide explicit constructions.
But what about the general?